Texture Painting Doesn't Work On Certain Objects
I can texture paint eveything else than the one that I want to paint.
I did evything same for each object, added an image material, saved the image for it, and then painted on the texture paint mode, but whenever I do it with my cupcake cup, insead of painting where I click it changes the whole color.
My brush isn't too big or anything to color it completely.
Also I saved it but it seems to show the name as untitled anyway


hello please pack your image and share your object

Before texture painting you have to check if the mesh has already been "UV unwrapped" properly. The mesh is made up of vertices and the painting on it is made up of image pixels. The computer doesn't know the relationship between them, so you have to cut the mesh like a paper shell manually and flatten it on the image plane.
